# How can I get the ref of the wrapped component of DragSource of react-dnd?

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I have a simple React component that I export wrapped with the `DragSource` high order component of `react-dnd`. I need to give a reference to my original component to call a public method on it, but can't find anything on the library docs.

What am I missing?